# Enable a Button when String in TextField is more than 5 characters

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield

I want to enable my b_changepw when I enter more than 5 characters in my textfield1. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
String test = textfield1.getText(); 

if () {
    b_changepw.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I don't know what to put inside if ()

Comment: String objects have a `length()` method.

Comment: do you want to do that at a runtime or only while you initialize your field?

Comment: @alex2410 - I want to enable it while typing in the textfield

Comment: use @CatalinaIsland advice with `DocumentFilter` using, it does what you want.

Comment: i changed my code..try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `TextField`, use a `JTextField`. Then add a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) that enables or disables the button depending on the text length.